# conda create --name doc-env python==3.7, но версия, указанная с помощью python -V, 3.11

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, virtualenv, conda

Я пытаюсь установить python 3.7 с помощью conda, но каждый раз, похоже, получаю python 3.11. Затем я попытался явно указать канал с помощью `conda create --name doc-env python=3.7 -c conda-forge` Я заметил, что слева в скобках не видно окружения. Как я могу установить свою версию python в свое окружение? Кроме Anaconda, у меня на машине нет Python. Похоже, что это происходит из-за того, что `which python` не указывает правильное направление. На самом деле он выдает:

```
/c/Users/antoi/anaconda3/python
```

В то время как он должен возвращать:

```
/c/Users/antoi/anaconda3/envs/doc-env/bin/python
```

Я подозреваю, что мой терминал не может загрузить среду. К сожалению, я не знаю достаточно о терминалах Windows, чтобы посоветовать решение.

Вот как были созданы среда и ошибка. Если вы хотите повторить это. Или посмотреть, что привело к ошибке:

```
PS C:\Users\antoi\Documents\document-qa-webui> conda create --name doc-env python==3.7        
WARNING: A conda environment already exists at 'C:\Users\antoi\anaconda3\envs\doc-env'
Remove existing environment (y/[n])? Y

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: unsuccessful attempt using repodata from current_repodata.json, retrying with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 23.7.4
  latest version: 23.9.0

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda

Or to minimize the number of packages updated during conda update use

     conda install conda=23.9.0



## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\antoi\anaconda3\envs\doc-env

  added / updated specs:
    - python==3.7


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    python-3.7.0               |       hea74fb7_0        16.6 MB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        16.6 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  certifi            pkgs/main/win-64::certifi-2022.12.7-py37haa95532_0
  pip                pkgs/main/win-64::pip-22.3.1-py37haa95532_0
  python             pkgs/main/win-64::python-3.7.0-hea74fb7_0
  setuptools         pkgs/main/win-64::setuptools-65.6.3-py37haa95532_0
  vc                 pkgs/main/win-64::vc-14.2-h21ff451_1
  vs2015_runtime     pkgs/main/win-64::vs2015_runtime-14.27.29016-h5e58377_2
  wheel              pkgs/main/win-64::wheel-0.38.4-py37haa95532_0
  wincertstore       pkgs/main/win-64::wincertstore-0.2-py37haa95532_2


Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
#
# To activate this environment, use
#
#     $ conda activate doc-env
#
# To deactivate an active environment, use
#
#     $ conda deactivate

PS C:\Users\antoi\Documents\document-qa-webui> conda activate doc-env
PS C:\Users\antoi\Documents\document-qa-webui> python -V
Python 3.11.5
```

Comment: Ну значит у вас и та и та версия питона, в разных каталогах. Используйте окружение `doc-env` и будет вам нужная версия питона. Зайдите в каталог окружения, там всё лежит, в подкаталоге `Scripts`, кажется, там питон.

Comment: Да @CrazyElf , я пытаюсь попасть туда, выполнив `conda activate doc-env`, как вы можете видеть в последних строках фрагмента кода. Но когда я выполняю активацию, в скобках нет `(environnement)`, указанной слева. Интересно, это потому, что я запускаю VSCode из Anaconda Navigator? Он мог бы предположить, что уже находится в окружении `(base)`? Но это меня бы удивило.

Comment: А в `VSCode` среду исполнения нужно выбирать где-то в интерфейсе из списка. У меня это справа внизу, рядом с кодировкой файла. Увидите где-то там слово Python и название выбранной среды - нажмите на неё, и там будет выбор из ваших виртуальных сред.